# Partical match string between columns for multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, match, substitution, partial

I have a list of dataframes (df1, df2, df3) for which I would like to match columns with another dataframe (df) and substitute strings only if there is a match. Match should be based on a string specified when running the function, specified as partial match, in other words here it only for fields containing string "TEXT" and should work on cases like TEXT123 and TEXTabc. I did not get very far myself...

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("TEXT333","b","c"), column_A = 1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("b","TEXT345","d"), column_A = 4:6, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("c","TEXT123","a"), column_A = 7:9, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- data.frame(name = c("TEXT333","TEXT123","a", "TEXT345", "k", "l", "b","c", "f"), column_B = 11:19, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


list<-c(df1, df2, df3)
```

example for df1

```
partial_match <- function(column_A$df1, column_B, TEXT, df) {
  df1_new <-df1
  df1_new[, column_B] <- ifelse(grepl("TEXT.*", df1[, column_A]),
                           df[, column_B] - nchar(TEXT),
                           df[, column_B])
  df1_new
}
```

Outcome for df1:

```
name column_A column_B
TEXT333        1        11
b        2        b
c        3        c
```

Comment: some sample data and desired output would help

Comment: uploaded a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using a for loop. You were close! Note that I changed your reference dataframe name to `dfs` to avoid confusion with `list()`.

Do you think you might encounter a situation where you might match multiple times in the same dataframe? If so, what I show below won't work without a couple more lines.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("TEXT333","b","c"), column_A = 1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("b","TEXT345","d"), column_A = 4:6, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("c","TEXT123","a"), column_A = 7:9, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
df <- data.frame(name = c("TEXT333","TEXT123","a", "TEXT345", "k", "l", "b","c", "f"), column_B = 11:19, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# loop over all dataframes in your list
for(i in 1:length(dfs)){
  
  # get name that matches regex
  val <- grep(pattern = "*TEXT*", x = dfs[[i]]$name, value = TRUE)
  
  # use name to update value from reference df
  dfs[[i]][dfs[[i]]$name == val,"column_A"] <- df[df$name == val,"column_B"]
}
```

Updated answer that can account for multiple matches in the same df

```
for(i in 1:length(dfs)){
  vals <- grep(pattern = "*TEXT*", x = dfs[[i]]$name, value = TRUE)
  for(val in vals){
    dfs[[i]][dfs[[i]]$name == val, "column_A"] <- df[df$name == val,"column_B"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple matches, so another solution is needed :)

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate multiple matches in the same df. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: I think it works, just need to figure out how to output those dataframes, e.g. df[i]<=dfs[[i]]

Comment: A quick and dirty way... `for(i in 1:length(dfs)){assign(x = paste0("df_result_", i), value = dfs[[i]])}`

Comment: Somehow it works with the example, but gives missing value in the real case

Comment: Which part gives a missing value? The code in my answer or my comment?

Comment: the main code, but only with my original data, that is strange. It maps well the strings containing TEXT, but returns NAs only for these

Comment: My code is set up to detect strings that have "TEXT" in them somewhere. Does your original data need to match to a different pattern? If so, you can update the `pattern =` argument in `grep()`.